# Map Expression<Func<Dto, bool>> to Expression<Func<Entity, bool>> using AutoMapper

Tags: c#, linq, automapper

I have a repository->service architecture that uses a LINQ expression to filter many data. Repositories work with entities and Services with the DTOs. At the moment, I use Automapper to map entity to dto and vice-versa. In the repository, I have a method that accepts an Expression> LINQ expression. This method is called by the service using an Expression> LINQ expression. So, I've used Automapper to map the service's expression to the repository's expression.
The project builds successfully but I have an error at runtime.

This is the method that throws the error in the service:

```
public IQueryable<TDto> GetBy(Expression<Func<TDto, bool>> predicate)
            => this.Repository.GetBy(Mapper.Map<Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>>(predicate))
                .ProjectTo<TDto>(Mapper.ConfigurationProvider);
```

And this is the method called in the repository:

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> GetBy(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
            => this.Context.Set<TEntity>().AsNoTracking().Where(predicate);
```

The mapping between entity and dto is the following:

```
CreateMap<TEntity, TDto>();

CreateMap<TDto, TEntity>();
```

At runtime I'm receiving this error:

```
AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: 'Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.'
```

Also, i've tryed to map explicitly the expressions:

```
CreateMap<Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>, Expression<Func<TDto, bool>> >();

CreateMap<Expression<Func<TDto, bool>>, Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>>();
```

But i've received this error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Code supposed to be unreachable'
```

Does anyone have a possible solution?

Answer (score 2):

I have never seen capability to automaticaly transform lambdas.
What you should do instead is to try use `Project` method.

For example:

```
var predicate = new Func<Dto, bool>(d => d.Id == 2);
var query = mapper.ProjectTo<Dto>(entities, null).Where(predicate);
```

Query will be equivalent of:

```
var query = entities
    .Select(e => new Dto { Id = e.Id, [...] }) // mapping created using map registered in AutoMapper
    .Where(d => d.Id == 2)
```

Another thing you can do is to map expression by yourself. As a starpoint you can use query produced by `Project` method:

```
var query = mapper.ProjectTo<Dto>(entities, null);
var lambda = (LambdaExpression)((UnaryExpression)((MethodCallExpression) query.Expression).Arguments[1]).Operand;
var body = (MemberInitExpression)lambda.Body;
var bindings = body.Bindings;
```

As a result of the code above you will have array of bindings like `dto.Id = entity.Id`.
Having that it should be pretty easy to write custom mapper:

```
public static class MapperExtensions
{
    public static Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> ConvertPredicate<TDto, TEntity>(this Mapper mapper, Expression<Func<TDto, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return (Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>)new PredicateVisitor<TDto, TEntity>(mapper).Visit(predicate);
    }

    public class PredicateVisitor<TDto, TEntity> : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        private readonly ParameterExpression _entityParameter;
        private readonly MemberAssignment[] _bindings;

        public PredicateVisitor(Mapper mapper)
        {
            IQueryable<TDto> mockQuery = mapper.ProjectTo<TDto>(new TEntity[0].AsQueryable(), null);
            LambdaExpression lambdaExpression = (LambdaExpression)((UnaryExpression)((MethodCallExpression) mockQuery.Expression).Arguments[1]).Operand;

            this._bindings = ((MemberInitExpression)lambdaExpression.Body).Bindings.Cast<MemberAssignment>().ToArray();
            this._entityParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity));
        }

        // This is required to modify type parameters
        protected override Expression VisitLambda<T>(Expression<T> node)
        {
            return Expression.Lambda(
                base.Visit(node.Body),
                node.Parameters.Select(p => (ParameterExpression)base.Visit(p)).ToArray()
            );
        }

        // Do member mapping
        protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
        {
            MemberInfo member = node.Member;
            MemberAssignment binding = this._bindings.FirstOrDefault(b => b.Member == member);

            if (binding != null)
            {
                return base.Visit(binding.Expression);
            }

            return base.VisitMember(node);
        }

        // Replace parameters reference
        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
        {
            if (node.Type == typeof(TDto))
            {
                return this._entityParameter;
            }
            if (node.Type == typeof(TEntity))
            {
                return this._entityParameter;
            }

            return base.VisitParameter(node);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! This solution really resolved my problem! The only thing i did is to use the interface IMapper instead.

Thank you very much!